# Formatting numbers on a graph on the horizontal axis in reporting services SSRS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am working with report services from Visual Studio 2019 and I am making a stacked bar type chart where I need to format the values to percentage, and indeed I have been able to do it but I can not format the horizontal axis, it shows me very large numbers, I have tried in axis properties > axis range and interval, but putting an interval, maximum, etc, has not worked I am already losing my mind, I have searched many sites where the different solutions do not work for me.

I need to show in the horizontal axis values like 0, 20, 40, 60, etc... but as you can see they are too big values, is there any way to format those numbers to show me only the first two digits or something like that? I can not make a division for that because the data is varying, if someone has gone through the same please I need your help, thank you very much.

[image: 1]

Comment: I suggest a screenshot of what you are getting, and an edited screenshot of what you are trying to accomplish. Its hard to describe this clearly in text.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I edited the post.

Comment: Divide the number by 1000000.

Comment: Do you want the axis to show as a percentage (0 - 100%) ? If so then I would calcualte the values in the chart series to be percentages then then you can fix the axis interval and min/max as you like. Show some sample data is this does not help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, but unfortunately, it does not work. First of all, I can not multiply by 1000000 because the values come from the database and vary, and indeed I set the min/max values to be 0 - 100 without the percent sign, I just want that sign to be seen in the bars, however, the bars come out of the graph, I have tried to format the horizontal axis but it does not work either, I have tried with LEFT() but it alters the actual values.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear, my level of English is low.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

On the Horizontal Axis properties, you can set the `LabelsFormat` property in the Property pane or the `Custom Format` in the Property pop-up to be dynamic based on the values.

[image]

[image]

```
=SWITCH(MAX(Fields!DATA.Value) > 1000000, "0,,M;(0,,)M", 
        MAX(Fields!DATA.Value) > 1000, "0,K;(0,)K", 
        1 = 1, "0,;(0,)")
```

This will show values in the millions as 1M, 2M, etc. while thousands would be displayed as 1K, 2K...

The expression ( `MAX(Fields!DATA.Value)` ) will vary based on the charts' data.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, it seems to me a good solution, but in my work they ask me to show values of two digits (0 - 100), obviously of 3 digits if it reaches 100 but not more than that, the idea is that it is equal to the numbers of the bars, very good answer that certainly at some point I will apply, anyway I am grateful for your answer.